# Some warning logs printed to console when running next js app in dev mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, next.js, eslint

Some warning logs are printing to the console when I start my next js application on dev mode. These logs seem to be related to eslint configurations of dependencies that are used in my project. I have made sure that the node_modules folder is on the root level as suggested in other places.

Warnings

```
Referenced from: /Users/xxxxxx/node_modules/function-bind/.eslintrc

./node_modules/function-bind/implementation.js
Failed to load config "@ljharb" to extend from.
Referenced from: /Users/xxxxxx/node_modules/function-bind/.eslintrc

./node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet-src.js
Failed to load config "mourner" to extend from.
Referenced from: /Users/xxxxxx/node_modules/leaflet/package.json

./node_modules/attr-accept/dist/es/index.js
Failed to load config "okonet" to extend from.
Referenced from: /Users/xxxxx/node_modules/attr-accept/.eslintrc
```

Code which invokes eslint on dev mode

````
```webpack: (config, { dev, isServer }) => {
      if (dev) {
        config.module.rules.push({
          test: /\.(jsx?)$/,
          loader: "eslint-loader",
          exclude: [
            "/node_modules/",
            "/.next/"
          ],
          enforce: "pre",
          options: {
            emitWarning: true
          }
        });
      }```
````

Code Structure
[image]

Is there a way to get rid of them? All help is welcome :)